# Building FreeMarker not resolving dependencies

Tags: ant, freemarker, dependency-management, ivy

I'm trying to build freemarker projects and failed in first steps,

I have JDK 8 and download latest IVY (2.5.0) or recommended (2.4.0) and copy to ant lib folder, ant version is 1.10.1

I execute `ant clean jar ide-dependencies` and got 2 UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES errors:

> ```
> [ivy:cachepath]                 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> [ivy:cachepath]                 ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
> [ivy:cachepath]                 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> [ivy:cachepath]                 :: ant#ant;1.6.5: not found
> [ivy:cachepath]                 :: avalon-logkit#avalon-logkit;2.0: not found
> [ivy:cachepath]                 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
> ```
>
> You need JDK 8 (not JDK 9!), Apache Ant (tested with 1.9.6) and Ivy (tested with 2.4.0)

Should I downgrade ant to make it work?

In [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) downgrade discouraged

> Older releases of Ant can be found here. We highly recommend to not use those releases but upgrade to Ant's latest release.

Comment: It works for me with Ant 1.10.5 and Ivy 2.4.0, but of course it should work with different versions too. Said artifacts are in the Maven Central Repo too. Maybe delete `~/.ant/cache/ant`, `~/.ant/cache/avalon-logkit`, and the `.ivy` directory from the FreeMarker project directory, and retry. Also check if there's something interesting in the logs.

Comment: @ddekany Thank for comment, it help until failed to delete a folder that wasn't there before execution `\freemarker-2.3-gae\.ivy\repo\biz.aQute\bnd\bnd-1.50.0.jar` . can this be ignored?

Comment: I see why. Just issue the same command again, and then it should work. The problem happens if you run multiple ant tasks at once, and it's the very first time you do a build on a fresh checkout. Then for each tasks it will try to re-create `.ivy`, not only for the first task of the run, and that leads to this 2nd problem.

Comment: @ddekany if I don't delete I get problem 1, if I delete I get problem 2... I'm new to ivy, should I ask in support forum?

Comment: Then certainly the reason of problem 1 is that problem 2 corrupts `.ivy`. So, delete the corrupted `.ivy`, then issue `ant clean jar` which should succeed, and then, in a separate command, `ant ide-dependencies`, which now should succeed as well. (I will look into this build problem... or will modify the README if I can't fix it.)

Comment: @ddekany working, thanks, you can write an answer and I'll accept and upvote

Comment: I have summarized this as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the build of 2.3.28 and earlier has this issue that if you run the build for the very first time (so you don't yet have `<freemarker-project>/.ivy` directory), and you run multiple Ant tasks (`jar` and `ide-dependencies`) with the same `ant` call, the 2nd task will corrupt the content of the newly created `<freemarker-project>/.ivy`. To fix that, you have to delete `<freemarker-project>/.ivy`, then run `ant clean jar`, and then separately run `ant ide-dependencies`.

Update: Fixed from 2.3.29-SNAPSHOT